# Coovachilli Mac Authentication

Tags: radius, captive-portal

I'm running coovachilli 1.2.5 and want to use mac authentication. I'm using

```
--macauth --macreauth --macpasswd macpass
```

in my command line. Based on tcpdump, and on my radius log, my MAC address is being authenticated and Radius is responding with an Accept, and the appropriate reply parameters.

For some reason, when I try to go to a webpage coovachilli still redirects me to the splash screen I use for authenticating normal users. Every time I go to a new page I can see radius authenticate my MAC address, and I still get redirected to the splash screen.

When I run

```
chilli-query list
```

I see my MAC address in the "dnat" state

```
00-22-19-F7-7F-C0 10.192.156.2 dnat 4dc12a6a00000001 0 00-22-19-F7-7F-C0 0/0 0/0 700/0 1924/0 0 0 97%/0 92%/0 http://www.google.com/
```

Any ideas on what is happening? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: You should ask about this on `CoovaChilli` forum: http://www.coova.org/forum/19